# How can an endonym for a specific group mean "people" or "humans" in this group at the same time?

Tags: lexicon

I understand that some people who speak Inuktitut self-designate as "Inuit" which allegedly means "people", or "human beings" or something similar. I've heard the same about people who are described with the exonym "Shoshone" calling themselves "newe" (or a similar term), which is supposed to mean "humans" or "people". Similar translations of endonyms as "people" or "human" seem to exist elsewhere.

But I don't understand how this works. Let's say in Inuktitut, is Inuit only used to self-refer to a more ore less defined group of people? But then the translation of "people" sounds highly misleading. Let's assume the etymology of Pусский ("Russian") became obscured, but people in the area of today's Russia still referred to themselves as "Pусский". Then it certainly would be misleading to say "many people in Eastern Europe and northern Asia call themselves 'Pусский', which in their language simply means 'humans' ". Or are endonyms such as newe or Inuit used as an endonym in one context, but in other contexts used to describe other people in general as well? Thus would it be, depending on context, be correct to say in Shoshoni "there are about 1000 newe, most of them in Idaho", and "there are currently living 8 billion newe on Earth"?
I've asked this question in the linguistics subreddit, and the answers that came up stated either:

1. newe and Inuit can mean people in general or people of the specific group, depending on context
2. newe and Inuit can mean only people of the specific group, in which case translating both to "people" or "humans" is misleading
3. newe and Inuit meant people in general in the past and later became an endonym after intense context to other groups outside. I find option 3 believable for Inuit, who may have had little contact to culturally and linguistically different groups, but not so plausible for newe/Shoshones.

I understand that there may not be a single answer for all groups in which this phenomenon exists, but I would be very grateful for some input.

Comment: I can't speak for Inuit or Shoshone, but the same phenomenon occurs all over the more remote parts of Papua New Guinea. From personal experiece I can tell you that many tribes there genuinely consider neighbouring tribes on par with animals, not humans in any sense we would; they hunt them, cook them and eat them if the opportunity presents itself. Fortunately this behaviour is in decline, but the mindset still persists quite strongly. To many of these tribes, they themselves are the only people, though the white man is also considered human by some.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the details in any specific cases but if the large majority of people you interact with belong to your people group, then the word "person" or "human" will be assumed to refer to a member of your group by default because a person not belonging to your group would be notable enough to require an explicit statement by the maxim of quantity

It's only if you have a reasonable chance of talking about people belonging to other people groups that this assumption ceases to work, and the word "person" become a general term for human first and foremost

As a related example in English, "cat" is generally assumed to refer to domestic cats, but can also be used to refer to any member of felid, a much wider category. Calling a lion "a cat" is not wrong, but in most circumstances is inappropriate because we are expected to clarify that we are referring to a non-prototypical example

Another related example is "mann" in Old English which, whilst definitely meaning "person" and not "man", was generally assumed to be a man by default, unless context made it clear the more general sense was meant

With that in mind, I suspect that both of the statements "there are about 1000 newe, most of them in Idaho", and "there are currently living 8 billion newe on Earth" would be accepted as correct, although the latter would probably be felt to be oddly, confusingly, or even misleadingly worded (depending on how strong the context and background knowledge is felt to be)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Your analogy with "cat" seems plausible to me, and a word changing its meaning dependent on context is certainly not unheard of. However, I have received contradicting answers to this question, similar to the one given by @Yellow Sky, and I would thus preferrably wait for a referenced answer before accepting.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the state of things with the Inuktitut or Shoshoni, but I can tell you how it works in Romani, an Indo-Aryan macrolanguage of the [Romani people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romani_people) living around the globe in different countries. I live in Ukraine and here there are many Romani communities, of 3 or 4 dialectal groups, so my information comes directly from the native speakers.

The Romani are widely known in English by the exonym Gypsies, the endonym being *rroma* “people” (pl.), *rrom* “man (of the Roma ethnic group), husband”. Although *rroma* does mean “people”, it is used exclusively to mean “people *of the Roma ethnic group*”, for any outsiders, non-Roma, there's another word, [*gadjó*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gadjo_(non-Romani)) “man of a non-Roma ethnicity, stranger, outsider”. Besides, *gadjó* has other negative connotations, the main point being Roma call only themselves “people, men”, all the rest are “gadjó, non-people”.

On the other hand, there is a Romani word meaning “a human being”, encompassing term which includes "rroma" as well as "gadjó", that's *manúš* (sg. = pl.). Also, the Kaldarash dialect of Romani has the word *lúmya* (borrowed from Romanian [lume](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lume#Noun_9)) meaning “1. world; 2. people; 3. humanity, mankind”.

*I wrote it in a commentary below, but let it be here, too:*
Since 99.9% of Romani speakers are native Roma, if one addresses people in Romani there's no need to use other word than *rromale* (Vocative case sg.), those to whom you talk in Romani are *always* Roma, that's why ‘people’ = ‘Roma’ in Romani.

Comment: if rroma is used exclusively to mean people of the Roma ethnic group, then in what sense does it mean "people"? Surely it means "people of the Roma ethnic group"?

Comment: It does mean "people", but since Roma call only Roma “people”, externally, for a non-Roma it means "people of the Roma ethnic group". There's no contradiction, just two points of view: from inside the community and from outside.

Comment: this is nonsensical. The only way it can be meaningful to say "rroma means people" is if it can include non-Roma, even if it would be assumed to refer to Roma by default. Otherwise it does not in any way mean "people", it is simply an autonym and "rroma means rroma" is the best that can be said

Comment: and if you do insist this statement does make sense, you're simply repeating the statement the OP is confused by, rather than explaining how it makes sense, and this is no answer

Comment: @Tristan - You could read the Wiki articles I gave links to. You simply failed to understand what I was driving at: Roma do not consider _gadjo_ humans, at least the Romani language works this way. The same situation like when intelligent centipede robots from Sirius come to Earth you won't call them “people”, will you? People are **we**, they are not people, they are **aliens**, gadjo. That's how it work. That's racism, bro.

Comment: @EpicBroccoli -  If the robots from Sirius call themselves “people” in their own tongue, it makes no difference for us humans, the robots still remain **aliens** for us.

Comment: your claim is not supported by your links, or the many productive conversations I have had only with Romani people who made every indication that they did in fact consider me a person. With your example of the aliens from Sirius, by definition their word would not mean "people" if it did not include "people", it would mean "Sirian". Your answer is not an answer, your example here is just reiterating that not an answer, and the comment before seems to make baseless antiziganist accusations and is not suitable for this site

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I'm not a linguist, far from it, and perhaps that makes it diffcult for me to understand your answer. However, if I understand you correctly, then there is no encompassing term in Romani which includes "rroma" as well as "gadjo"? I could imagine that this might be the case in Inuktitut as well as Shoshoni, perhaps interaction to other groups used to be so limited that no encompassing term was necessary (this is pure speculation on my part)? However, I still believe that the translation as "people" or "humans" is confusing then, since the concept of...

Comment: ... "people" would than be so different from the concept in the English language, that no translation would be better than translating as "humans" or "people". Also, I would be quite surprised if there at least now exists no encompassing term similar to the English "people" in newe, Inuktitut or Romani.

Comment: @Tristan - I am no way an antiziganist. Naturally, Romani people consider those outside their communities persons. Nowadays. Still the evidence of their language suggests ti used to be not so. And Romani is not an exception, remember Greeks calling non-Greeks _bárbaroi_, or Slavs calling Germanic peoples _*němьci_ “the dumb, the mute”, this word is still used in half of the Slavic languages for “Germans”. So will you call me Russophobic if I say Ru _немец_ (némets) “German” actually means “dumb one”? That's etymology, nothing more, Russians use this word now without thinking about its origin.

Comment: you are yet to provide any justification for your claim that rroma means person (which might enable this to be an answer), and so have also failed to back up the claim that "Roma do not consider gadjo humans" which, absent any justification certainly smacks of antiziganism

Comment: and it is quite different to call someone "mute" (a clear reference to not having intelligible speech, likewise barbaroi) and saying they are not human. And when claims that Roma and Jews don't consider outsiders humans have been part of the rhetoric used to justify their oppression for centuries and genocides against them, I don't think it's unreasonable to expect more than waved hands as justification for the claim

Comment: @EpicBroccoli - There is a Romani word meaning “a human being”, encompassing term which includes "rroma" as well as "gadjo", that's _manuš_ (sg=pl). I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @YellowSkyI don't fully understand your analogy with Greeks and Slavs. Is your claim that Πανέλλανες (assuming I correctly googled the endonym for ancient Greeks) might be translated as "people" or "humans" in ancient texts, since a Greek exonym for all non-Greeks existed?

Comment: @Yellow Sky thank you for the information regarding manuš. So, if I understand you correctly, there exist three relevant terms: 1. rroma (all "insiders"), 2. gadjo (all "outsiders"), 3. manuš ("in-" and "outsiders"). In this case, would it not be best to translate manuš as people, and not to attempt to translate rroma as people?

Comment: @EpicBroccoli - Look, your question was about nations whose endonym means “people” and whether it is applied to people outside those nations, wasn't it? I gave you example of a nation whose endonym means “people” and which is _not _ applied to people outside those nations. What's wrong? Do you mean they have no books in biology in Romani? Do you mean a language that big as Romani in the 21st century has no word for humans in general? What's the sense in you hypercriticism? What is not clear?

Comment: @Yellow Sky Regarding your analogy with Robo-Sirians: If the Robots, which have observed Earth, called themselves "X", humans "Y", and a group of robots and humans "XY", then would it not be strange if they deciphered our language and then wrote in their Robo-Wikipedia "Y call themselves 'humans', which literally means 'XY' "? Would it not be more accurate to simply claim "Y call themselves 'humans' "?

Comment: _Rroma_ **does mean** “people”. When you enter a bar you shout, “Hey, people! The drinks are on me!” In a similar situation and if there are Romas in the bar, a Roma would shout, “Hey, Rromale!” (Voc. case pl.) And that will mean “hey, people!”, not “hey, Romani!”, just the same way as it is hard to imagine someone in that situation shouting “Hey, Americans!” or “Hey, Englishmen!”

Comment: @YellowSky would they be including non-romani people in the bar? If so, then the translation as people is reasonable. If, in accordance with everything you've said so far, they wouldn't, the translation as "people" seems untenable, and it's more analogous to "hey americans". That americans would be unlikely to say such a thing is cultural and not linguistic

Comment: @EpicBroccoli - As for robots, you're right, that'd be strange. But it's quite possible that _it is the robots_ who will be surprised with the Y seeing themselves different from X, with Y feeling _not_ like a part of XY. The X robots don't see other species different from them, that's why they just come to get their brethren back under the rule of _our common Authority_. As for the bar, since the claim is in the Romani language, it will hardy be understood by _gadjo_ if they are in the bar. :D

Comment: Please understand that I am not trying to engage in hypercriticism, I am genuinely trying to understand, which I have trouble to do. Perhaps my question was unclear. It was not meant to be about how people whose endonym is translated as "people" refer to outsiders. It was about how it is a meaningful translation to translate this endonym as "people". If one Rom wrote in his diary "I had drinks with all the rrom in the bar", and that means with all those in the bar belonging to the Romani people, and not other guests, then it seems misleading to translate to "...all the people in the bar".

Comment: @YellowSky regarding the Sirian robots: That is my point I think. Even if the robots are surprised that humans do not consider themselves as XY, why would they translate 'human' as 'XY'?

Comment: @EpicBroccoli - Since 99.9% of Romani speakers are native Roma, if you address people in Romani there's no need to use other word than _rromale_, those to whom you talk in Romani are _always_ Roma, that's why ‘people’=‘Roma’ in Romani. As for robots, they could translate 'human' as 'XY' because they think that since _they_ call themselves ‘XY’, _all the other_ endonyms _also_ mean ‘XY’, and ‘human’ too. It's just the same way as most nations on Earth think that “people” means “_all_ the humans” in _all_ the languages, but it's not so, in fact.

Comment: @YellowSky You seem to focus on addressing people, but, since most speakers are insiders as you say, this seems to be misleading. As a comparison, the n-word is used by certain black people addressing each other, but I'm pretty sure I've encountered it used by these people to address white people as well. I would not use this to argue that the n-word simply means 'people' in these circles (though I can't claim to know that it's not). Perhaps you could call it a secondary meaning? Isn't it more informative to ask what Romani use to _describe_ people?

Comment: @EdvinW - Note the substantial difference between the word ‘_rroma_’ and what you call ‘n-word’: the former is an _endonym_, the main word used by Roma to call themselves, the latter is an _exonym_ considered offensive when used by non-Africans. One can hardly compare them. Also, I know a native Ukrainian who can speak Romani well, he knows their culture, lots of songs, etc., and Roma who know him do call him _rrom_, namely _parno rrom_ “White Roma”. Since in Ukraine there are no African communities, I'm not sure about the ‘n-word’, but _rrom_ means “a person belonging to Romani community.”

Comment: There seems to be a disagreement about just what the phrase "'rroma' means 'people'" means. I think to most of us, "'rroma' means 'people'" means that the set of things which Roma consider "rroma" is essentially the same as the set of things which English speakers consider "people." But, @YellowSky, you have stated yourself that this is not the case; Roma consider only Roma to be "rroma" whereas English speakers consider all humans to be "people."

Comment: You seem to be using "'rroma' means 'people'" to mean something like "Roma use the word 'rroma' in more or less the same situations that English speakers use the word 'people.'" Maybe it would be accurate to say that "rroma" doesn't literally or denotationally mean "people," but it does connotationally or practically mean "people"—much like how if one person exclaims "Jesus!" and another person exclaims "Heavens!" then their exclamations don't have the same literal meaning (since Jesus is not the heavens), but they have the same "practical" meaning.